# SQL Server Query hangs with fetch first 10 rows but not without it

Tags: sql-server, select, trim

When I run

```
select d.part, d."key" 
from dbo.orderdtl d 
inner join dbo.dwgroute r on ltrim(d.part) = ltrim(r.partmade) 
order by d.part offset 0 rows
```

It returns 13 rows and the query takes about half a second, but when I run

```
select d.part, d."key" 
from dbo.orderdtl d 
inner join dbo.dwgroute r on ltrim(d.part) = ltrim(r.partmade) 
order by d.part 
      offset 0 rows fetch first 10 rows only
```

the query hangs and will never return any result.

Oddly, getting rid of the `ltrim`s so the query reads

```
select d.part, d."key" 
from dbo.orderdtl d 
inner join dbo.dwgroute r on d.part = r.partmade 
order by d.part 
      offset 0 rows fetch first 10 rows only
```

will also make the query execute quickly, but I do need to keep the `ltrim`s to get the desired result from the query.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this behavior? I'm using SQL Server 2017 (v14.0.3192.2).

Comment: Are you facing the same issue with top 10 as well?

Comment: It could be blocking, or a vastly different query plan.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use "next" instead of "first":

```
select d.part, d."key" 
from dbo.orderdtl d 
inner join dbo.dwgroute r on ltrim(d.part) = ltrim(r.partmade) 
order by d.part 
      offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

If your objective is to just see the top 10 you can also use:

```
select top 10 d.part, d."key" 
    from dbo.orderdtl d 
    inner join dbo.dwgroute r on ltrim(d.part) = ltrim(r.partmade) 
    order by d.part
```

Comment: I tried it with next as well but it has the same result